# Making a div content to "bleed" on the bottom (or prevent the background image to render)

Tags: html, css

Okey so basically I have:

```
<div id="content">
  ... content of arbitrary size ...
</div>
<div id="content_bottom"></div>
```

The style is:

```
#content {
    background: transparent url(content_tile.png) center top repeat-y;
    width: 800px;
}
#content_bottom {
    background: transparent url(content_bottom.png) center top no-repeat;
    height: 200px;
    width: 800px;
}
```

`content_tile.png` is a `800x1` image (tiles vertically), and has transparency.
`content_bottom.png` is a `800x200` image.

Basically, I need to have the `content_bottom.png` image to replace the `#content` background image only on the bottom.
Having a negative margin on `#content` almost works, but since both images are transparent images, they overlap, and it should not happen.

I think that I need to make `#content` not to render its background on the last 200px on its bottom.
Any idea how I could do that ?

Comment: Could you link to a live demo for this? Or show an image of what **is** happening, and an image showing what you **want** to happen? I'm having trouble visualising this, for some reason. =/

Comment: @ricebowl: http://saimaalakshmidevi.com/ <--- I've settle with the solution of splitting the content in two different divs (which isn't what I wanted but it works...)

Answer (score 0):

If you altered your markup slightly and used javascript you could do it with an absolutely positioned div that contained only the background.  Then onload, set #repeating-background's height to (#content's height - 200px):

**HTML**

```
<div id="content">
    <div id="text">
         This is where your content would go
    </div>      
    <div id="repeating-background"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#content {
   position: relative;
   width: 800px;
   background: url(content_bottom.png) left bottom no-repeat;
}

#text {
   position: relative;
   z-index: 2;
}

#repeating-background {
   position: absolute;
   z-index: 1;       
   top: 0;
   left: 0;       

   width: 800px;
   height: 1px;

   background: url(content_tile.png) left top repeat-y;
}
```

**Javascript (jQuery)**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#repeating-background').height($('#content').height() - 200);
});
```

Comment: I don't want to use javascript for this, only CSS.
With javascript the simplest solution would have been to     `$('#content').height($('#content').height() - 200);`
I've already tried and that would have worked. No need for the repeating background.

Answer (score -1):

create a third div, nested in #content, that is 200px height.

Comment: It won't work... the two background will overlap (and since they are transparent you will see both background)

Comment: @Pafy, how about if you put the third div *between* `#content` and `#content_bottom`?